# Json data in a list view returning null in base adapter class

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, actionbarsherlock

Hello everyone I am trying to display a list of json data in listview my class is extended with SherlockFragment fetched the data succesfully but unable to append the data in a list. for displaying of data I created a class which extending with baseadapter class. i have found that value is getting zero at View group

Can any one help in fixing the issue thanks in advance

```
public class AboutMeFragment extends SherlockFragment { 
String add_users;
View rootView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
static String getQuestionsStr,idStr,getMaxAnsLengthStr,userIdStr,userRankStr,de;
ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aboutme,
            container, false);
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new CheckLoginAboutmen().execute();     
    return rootView;
}

private class CheckLoginAboutmen extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{ 

    String json;
    String outputData = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

        //      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginName", loginStr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", "195"));
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        add_users = getString(R.string.about_me);
        json = sh.makeServiceCall(add_users, ServiceHandler.POST,params);
        Log.d("Create Prediction Request: ", "> " + json);

        System.out.println("The returned JSON Value is..."+json);

        try{
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            if(json != null){
                HashMap<String, String> contact = null;
                for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    getQuestionsStr = c.getString("GetQuestion");
                    idStr = c.getString("_id");
                    getMaxAnsLengthStr = c.getString("MaxAnswerLength");
                    userIdStr = c.getString("UserId");
                    userRankStr = c.getString("UserRank");

                    System.out.println("The Fetched Id is...."+idStr+"\n"+getQuestionsStr+"\n"+getMaxAnsLengthStr+"\n"+userIdStr+"\n"+userRankStr);

                    contact.put("getQuestionsStr", getQuestionsStr);

                }
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListViewAdapter la = new ListViewAdapter(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext(),contactList);
        //      ListViewAdapter la = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),contactList);
        System.out.println(getActivity()+"\n"+contactList);
        list.setAdapter(la);
    }

}
}
```

And my Adapter class code is

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
String question;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context baseContext,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    context = baseContext;
    data = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    View itemView = null;
    TextView textView1_lv_123;


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);        

    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent,false);     
    resultp = data.get(position);       
    textView1_lv_123 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1_lv_123);      
    System.out.println("The String to be fetched is...."+AboutMeFragment.getQuestionsStr);      
    textView1_lv_123.setText(resultp.get(AboutMeFragment.getQuestionsStr));

    return itemView;
}
}
```

Comment: Declare ListView object in OnCreateView.
  list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: Hi Shadow, I checked with that no change same issue returning

Comment: `i have found that value is getting zero`, which value?

Comment: Hi Xcihnegn, I am getting this value " resultp.get(AboutMeFragment.getQuestionsStr) "as null

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem in **adapter**..

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null; //this line
}
```

**return the object from your arrayList corresponding the position like below!**

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return data.get(position);
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: see updated answer and accept & vote up if it's helpful! @AdityaHariKishan

Comment: Thanks for your support still it returning Null value

Comment: Post your Log mention the line that causing the prob

Comment: it is just retuning the null even it is not showing any error logs too

Answer (score 0):

```
First thing is that you have just declared your ListView not initialized.

ListView list;
So you need to initialize it on main() method. Like,

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewname);
and also call your main() method before your AsyncTask been executed.

Another thing is that just set your adapter class out of your for loop.

list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    mylist));
```

Add this two lines in on create method                                                         list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListViewAdapter la = new ListViewAdapter(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext(),contactList);

Comment: Add this two lines in on create method                                                         list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListViewAdapter la = new ListViewAdapter(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext(),contactList);

Comment: Hi Alka, I have declared listview in main() method and modified the code in asynctask but no change

Comment: @AdityaHariKishan think its a context problem, pass context into  asyntask like declare context c=this , listview ListviewAdapter la=new ListViewAdapter(c,contactList)

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method, instead of this-

```
textView1_lv_123.setText(resultp.get(AboutMeFragment.getQuestionsStr));
```

write this-

```
textView1_lv_123.setText(resultp.get(position).get("getQuestionsStr"));
```

because your ArrayList is giving the Hashmap Object and from that Hashmap object you will get your data.

Comment: Hi Amit, I have done above modifications but the result is null

Comment: In the comment, you have written that you are the value " resultp.get(AboutMeFragment.getQuestionsStr) "as null. Are You still getting the value of that "null" ?

Comment: Amit, I tried in multiple ways to execute data is able to pass is correct but, when i am appending it to textview its getting null

Comment: Either "textView1_lv_123" or "resultp" will be null, can you show your Logcat trace?

Comment: resultp value is not null it is successfully displaying the result while appending to the textview it is displaying nothing and the result is null i am declaring in this way i.e resultp = data.get(position); & for text view tv.setText(resultp.get("GetQuestion"));